# issue configuring nginx to look for a file in other folder

Tags: nginx

As per http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule
I'm trying to make the server search for a file in a specific directory.
ie: http://exemple.com/sitemap.xml would look at rootFolder/sitemaps/specificname-sitemap.xml

I added this:

```
location  /sitemap.xml {
    alias  /sitemaps/specificname-sitemap.xml;
}
```

But it doesn't work. What am I missing?

EDIT:
My complete conf is:

```
    server {
        listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

        root /var/www/exemple/public;
        index       index.html index.htm index.php;
        server_name exemple.com;

        location  /sitemap.xml {
          alias  /sitemaps/cs-sitemap.xml;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

        location /doc/ {
                alias /usr/share/doc/;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                allow ::1;
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

                # With php5-cgi alone:
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                # With php5-fpm:
                #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

Comment: When you say, "It doesn't work", have you looked at the error log?  What response are you getting?  I'm willing to bet that the nginx user doesn't have permissions on the aliased file or path.

Comment: oh, sorry, I get a 404 not found.

Comment: Not to point out the absolute obvious, but did you restart nginx after making the configuration changes?  You can also test your nginx config files using the command 'nginx -t'.

Comment: Yes I restarted, and yes it return test successful.
Is it possible that 
location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

cause an interference?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
    location  /sitemap.xml {
      try_files $uri  /sitemaps/specificName-sitemap.xml;
    }
```